# Loading properties file from within JAR file with JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Here is the Maven structure of my project

```
app
  > common-module
  > webapp-module
  > batch-module
 pom.xml
```

The `common-module` exposes a `Version` class. This class is used by both webapp and batch modules.

The `Version` class has one unique static method called `get`. It returns the global version of the project.

The global version is stored in a properties file. When `get` is called from batch module (a standalone java application), the properties file is successfully loaded.

In the webapp, things are different. I have created a managed bean `VersionBean` that would permit any JSF page to call the `get` method. Whenever I use one of the following

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()

Thread.currentThread().getClassLoader()
```

I can never find the properties.file.

How can I load the properties file (getResourceAsStream) located in a jar file from a managed bean ?

**EDIT**
Here is the solution I came up with based on advice from @BalusC and @eljunior

**VersionBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class VersionBean {
    private String version;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        version = Version.get();
    }
}
```

**Version.java**

```
public class Version {
    public static String get() {
        InputStream is = Version.class.getResourceAsStream("/version.properties");

        // Read InputStream and return version string ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would delegate the loading of the properties file to the same classloader of the class `Version`: in the method get, use `Version.class.getResourceAsStream("yourFile.properties");`.

That should work anywhere the Version class can be loaded, so it would work in the webapp too (of course, provided the properties file actually *IS* inside the *common-module* jar file :).

Then your VersionBean could be an application scoped bean that just loaded the property on initializing the application, something like this:

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class VersionBean {
    private String version;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        version = Version.get();
    }
}
```

Note that if you are using a JSF version before 2.0, you'll have to configure the managed-bean in the `faces-config.xml` instead of using the annotations `@ManagedBean` and `@ApplicationScoped`.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure how Maven builds the WAR and where your properties file is *actually* located, but I can at least tell how `ExternalContext#getResourceAsStream()`,  `Thread#getContextClassLoader()` and `Class#getClassLoader()` all work differently.

1. **ExternalContext#getResourceAsStream()**
   The `ExternalContext#getResourceAsStream()` scans for webapp resources in web content folder (there where the WAR's `/WEB-INF` and `/META-INF` folders also reside) and in `/META-INF/resources` folder of any JAR files deployed in `/WEB-INF/lib` of the webapp. The supplied path is always relative to those root folders and should start with a `/`.

   ```
   InputStream input = externalContext
       .getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/version.properties");
   ```
2. **Thread#getContextClassLoader()**
   The `Thread#getContextClassLoader()` operates on the "root" of the classpath. This covers all folders covered by the classpath of the webapp, the appserver and the JVM. The supplied path is always relative to the classpath root and can **not** start with `/`. Note that when the properties file is enclosed in a package, then you should be treating the package structure as a file system path with `/` as separator. The below example assumes it to be in the package `com.example.version`.

   ```
   InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
       .getResourceAsStream("com/example/version/version.properties");
   ```
3. **Class#getClassLoader()**
   The `Class#getClassLoader()` operates relative to the location of the class itself. The supplied path can be either relative or absolute. If relative, then it's relative to the location of the class itself. If absolute, then it's absolute to the classpath root. Note that this does not necessarily have access to all other folders covered by the classpath. The below example assumes the properties file to be in the same package as the `VersionBean` class:

   ```
   InputStream input = VersionBean.class
       .getResourceAsStream("version.properties");
   ```

   Or when it's in another package, e.g. `com.example.other` (note the leading `/`):

   ```
   InputStream input = VersionBean.class
       .getResourceAsStream("/com/example/other/version.properties");
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. I wasn't aware that the methods would perform so differently. The absolute location of the properties file is as follow : `/WEB-INF/lib/batch-module.jar!/version.properties`

Comment: The `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("version.properties")` should then do.

Comment: I'm confused. This *is* solution #2. Eljunior's answer (basically solution #3 as in my answer) assumes it to be in the same package as the class which doesn't seem to be the case at all given your absolute location in JAR (given that packageless classes is a bad practice). Disclaimer: Maven is beyond me, so I can't tell from top of head how exactly it builds the JAR and WAR.

Comment: This solution #2 (the one I was doing initially) raises NullPointerException :\ However, trying solution **#3** works. I made a mistake in my last comment, sorry.